# How to fine-tune the deployment of a resource in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, azure-data-explorer, azure-rm

I have a terraform that builds a Kusto script resource with the actual script stored in a storage account:

```
    resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "acquisition-in-table-creation-scripts" {
      name                   = "acquisition-in-scripts.json"
      storage_account_name   = azurerm_storage_account.scripts-storage-account.name
      storage_container_name = azurerm_storage_container.scripts-container.name
      type                   = "Block"
      source_content         = templatefile("${path.module}/scripts/my-script.tftpl", { ** })
    }
    
    data "azurerm_storage_account_blob_container_sas" "blob-sas-token" {
          
          // Omitted for brevity
    }
        
    resource "azurerm_kusto_script" "kusto-script-execution" {
          
      force_an_update_when_value_changed = filesha1("${path.module}/scripts/my-script.tftpl")
          
      name                               = "script-execution"
      database_id                        = ***
      url                                = azurerm_storage_blob.table-creation-scripts.id
      sas_token                          = data.azurerm_storage_account_blob_container_sas.blob-sas-token.sas
      continue_on_errors_enabled         = false
        
      depends_on = [
            azurerm_storage_blob.table-creation-scripts
      ]
   }
```

I would like the `azurerm_kusto_script` to be replaced only if the file `my-script.tftpl` has changed. That is why I used the `force_an_update_when_value_changed` property to put the file hash in it.

However, since I have to specify the `sas_token` to access the storage account, the resource ends up being replaced every time the pipeline is being run simply because of the `sas_token` being different:

```
  # module.device-telemetry.azurerm_kusto_script.template must be replaced
-/+ resource "azurerm_kusto_script" "template" {
      ~ id                                 = "/subscriptions/***script-execution" -> (known after apply)
        name                               = "kusto-script-execution"
      ~ sas_token                          = (sensitive value) # forces replacement
        # (4 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
```

Initially I thought I could just use the `ignore_changes` lifecycle event and prevent the resource from being replaced if `sas_token` has changed. However if the file is changed for real, then the newly generated `sas_token` is ignored and the resource can't access the storage to get the script.

**Question**

How can I prevent the `azurerm_kusto_script` resource from being deployed if only the `sas_token` has changed?

Comment: since you technically have the script in the same codebase as this Terraform, have you tried removing the `sas_token` argument and using `script_content` argument instead, like `script_content = file("${path.module}/scripts/my-script.tftpl")` ?

Comment: @ZachKing It definitely worked! In hindsight, I do not know why I chose something so complicated...